# Select from Oracle table, date time value?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, datetime-format, to-char

I want to get the date time value from oracle tables.
This is my code

```
$conn = oci_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
$query_1 = "select max (p.navi_date), p.navi_user
from payments p
where p.pay_date >= trunc(sysdate)
and p.navi_user = 'HAS:WWW:PARDOXT'
group by  p.navi_user
order by 1";
$s_1 = oci_parse($conn, $query_1);
oci_execute($s_1);
//oci_fetch_all($s, $res);
oci_fetch_all($s_1, $arr_1);
$o_1 = $arr_1['MAX(P.NAVI_DATE)'];
echo($o_1[0]);
```

but it shows 11.06.15 without time. How can I select with time it?

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR(dateColumn,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM mytable;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> max (p.navi_date)

To display the date in your desired format, use **TO_CHAR** along with proper **format model**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') dt FROM dual;

DT
-------------------
06/11/2015 14:28:04

SQL>
```

Your modified query would look like:

```
SELECT to_char(max(p.navi_date), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')...
```

**NOTE** `TO_CHAR` converts **DATE** into **STRING** to display the datetime value in your desired format. For date arithmetic, you should leave the date as it is, use to_char only to display as a string, not for date arithmetic.

Comment: $query_1 = "SELECT to_char(max(p.navi_date), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), p.navi_user
from payments p

Comment: error: Notice: Undefined index: MAX(P.NAVI_DATE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\fintajonline\Online_Monitoring_Pays\index.php on line 21

Comment: What could be the problem??

Comment: In this case:
$query_1 = "SELECT to_char(max(p.navi_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')), p.navi_user
from payments p

Comment: Well, that's not an Oracle error. By the way, using `to_char` will convert date into string. Also, you did not apply filter in your above query. What happens when you do it in your original query?

Comment: I see 
Warning: oci_execute(): in C:\xampp\htdocs\fintajonline\Online_Monitoring_Pays\index.php on line 18

Warning: oci_fetch_all(): in C:\xampp\htdocs\fintajonline\Online_Monitoring_Pays\index.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: MAX(P.NAVI_DATE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\fintajonline\Online_Monitoring_Pays\index.php on line 21

Comment: $query_1 = "SELECT to_char(max(p.navi_date), 'MM.DD.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as ninja from bis.payments p
where p.pay_date >= trunc(sysdate)
and p.navi_user ='HAS:WWW:R_SIMKA'
group by  p.navi_user
order by 1";
$s_1 = oci_parse($conn, $query_1);
oci_execute($s_1,OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
//oci_fetch_all($s, $res);
while(($row = oci_fetch_array($s_1, OCI_BOTH))){
    echo "<option value='" . $row[0] . "' selected>".$row[0]."</option>";
}
This is way to get my solution